# obtener valor de <select> mediante un request

Tags: html, c

Estoy haciendo un web server en el lenguaje C y utilizando html. Necesito obtener en C a través de un http request el valor que tiene el select.

La idea de lo que estoy haciendo es, dar opciones de ordenar los archivos que estoy leyendo a través de un botón.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so], es muy importante que leas [ask], [¿has intentado algo?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2874/107347), [¿Qué has investigado?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2878/107347) para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad.

Comment: "*Necesito obtener en C a través de un http request el valor que tiene el select*" ¡ánimos! saber lo que se necesita es el primer paso del viaje, te deseo suerte en tu búsqueda.